# How to assign dictionary to another dictionary?

Tags: python, function, dictionary

So I want to create a function that accepts values for dictionary, creates new dictionary and returns it. Then I want to assign that value in other places of code. But I get Type Error dict object is not callable. How can I do this?

```
def shoe(brand, model):
    shoe = {}
    shoe['brand'] = brand
    shoe['model'] = model
    return shoe


 shoes_list = []
 shoe = {}

 shoe = shoe('Some Brand', 'Some model')

 print(shoe)
```

Comment: You overwrite the value of your shoe function when you create `shoe = {}` so when the program gets to `shoe('Some Brand', 'Some model')` it is references `shoe={}` and not the function

Comment: You can't use the same name for everything: `def shoe`, `shoe = {}`, `shoe = shoe(...)`

Comment: Thank you. It solves the issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def shoe(brand, model):
```

Here you create a function named `shoe`.

```
    shoe = {}
```

Now you create a variable named `shoe` and assign a dictionary to it. This isn't a problem yet since this variable is local inside of the function. However, it can be very confusing to reuse the same name in this way. I suggest changing this variable's name.

```
    shoe['brand'] = brand
    shoe['model'] = model
    return shoe


 shoes_list = []
 shoe = {}
```

Now you are reassigning the name `shoe` to refer to an empty dictionary instead of the function that it used to refer to. This will cause later calls to the function with `shoe()` to fail.

```
 shoe = shoe('Some Brand', 'Some model')
```

And then you try to assign the return value of the function to the name `shoe()`. I assume this is where the function call fails. Note that if you fix this, you don't need `shoe = {}` at all.

```
 print(shoe)
```

You are using the same name for two different things: once for the name of your function and once for the name of your dictionary. Use two different names to fix the problem. In general, function names should be verbs. So you can do `get_shoe()` or `create_shoe()` for the function name. Then using the noun `shoe` for the dictionary will be fine.

Comment: The name is actually used *three* times in one namespace and once in an other.

Comment: @KlausD. yes, I see that after more careful analysis which is addressed in my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need your function and your original dict to have different names:

```
def make_shoe(brand, model):
    shoe = {}
    shoe['brand'] = brand
    shoe['model'] = model
    return shoe


 shoes_list = []
 shoe = {}

 shoe = make_shoe('Some Brand', 'Some model')

 print(shoe)
```

Note also that you are not filling in the dict you stored in `shoe`; you are making a new dict to replace it. If you want to fill it in, you would do something like this:

```
def fill_in(brand, model, dest):
    dest['brand'] = brand
    dest['model'] = model


 shoes_list = []
 shoe = {}

 fill_in('Some Brand', 'Some model', shoe)

 print(shoe)
```